# Weblogic JMS Exception 055167 "cannot support more than one synchronous message-prefetching consumer."

Tags: java, spring, jms, weblogic

What does it mean?

I inherited a complex Java library with a failing integration test.  The library uses a general publish/subscribe paradigm, but I must confess I'm pretty inexperienced when it comes to any of this Weblogic/JMS/Spring stuff.    The test application runs on one server and invokes Java from C++ via JNI, and launches a child publisher process via fork (that publishes via JNI/Java).  THe main app is configured via Spring, and communicates with Weblogic JMS installed on another server (the Weblogic JMS server is controlled by another group on our project).  I managed to turn on spring jms debugging, which has been somewhat helpful.  So my log file is showing me a sequence of events like this:

```
(My App) Publishing...
org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory Creating cached JMS MessageProducer for destination [MY-JMS-Module!DataTest2]: weblogic.jms.client.WLProducerImpl@7b9a29
...
(My App) Publishing...
org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory Found cached JMS MessageProducer for destination [MY-JMS-Module!DataTest2]: weblogic.jms.client.WLProducerImpl@7b9a29
...
(My App) Publishing...
org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory Found cached JMS MessageProducer for destination [MY-JMS-Module!DataTest2]: weblogic.jms.client.WLProducerImpl@7b9a29
...
(My App) Subscribing to DataTest2
org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate Looking up JNDI object with name [DataTest2]
(My App) Launching publisher process...
org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver Located object with JNDI name [DataTest2]
org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory Creating cached JMS MessageConsumer for destination [MY-JMS-Module!DataTest2]: weblogic.jms.client.WLConsumerImpl@5e3eed51

(My App) Publishing....
org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory Creating cached JMS MessageProducer for destination [MY-JMS-Module!DataTest2]
...
WARN 2011-11-14 22:01:00,421 org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'DataTest2' - trying to recover. Cause: [JMSClientExceptions:055167]Single session cannot support more than one synchronous message-prefetching consumer.

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: [JMSClientExceptions:055167]Single session cannot support more than one synchronous message-prefetching consumer.
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSConsumer.receiveInternal(JMSConsumer.java:587)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSConsumer.receive(JMSConsumer.java:526)
    at weblogic.jms.client.WLConsumerImpl.receive(WLConsumerImpl.java:184)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachedMessageConsumer.receive(CachedMessageConsumer.java:74)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:429)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:310)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1058)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:947)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

I sure wish I had access to the Weblogic JMS source code to run down that exception right about now.  Any help or advice would be appreciated.  Like I said, the code is kind of complex, so I'm not sure I can provide much more info than my truncated log snipped above, without turning this into a novel.

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR version*

Try disabling Message Prefetch for one of the JMS Connection Factories within Weblogic Admin Console.

*Long Version*

Hope this helps since I'm not fully familiar with this aspect of Weblogic.

[The Basic Primer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/jms/implement.html#wp1313933) is this flowchart from the Oracle docs.

The log messages you have show the basic stuff happening as far as looking up the Connection Factory JNDI, Creating a Connection, Creating a Session from that Connection, Look up the destination JNDI, Registering the Consumers and Producers goes.

It seems to be failing after that when it realizes that **there are more than one consumer with prefetching enabled**.

This prefetch is a property of the [Synchronous Consumer which enables prefetching batches of messages to improve performance](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/jms/implement.html#wp1188496).
See the Sec titled **"Using the Prefetch Mode to Create a Synchronous Message Pipeline"**

From the Admin Console, Try [setting "Prefetch Mode for Synchronous Consumer" this to Disabled](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/ConsoleHelp/pagehelp/JMSjmsconnectionjmsconnectionfactoryconfigclientparamstitle.html)

The other docs I came across [are the Error Code](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/messages/JMSClientException.html) explanation

> BEA-055167   Error: Single session cannot support more than one
>   synchronous message-prefetching consumer.
>
> Description
>
> Single session cannot support more than one synchronous
>   message-prefetching consumer.
>
> Cause   - There is another opened
>   synchronous message-prefetching consumer.
>
> Action  - Close the another synchronous message-prefetching consumer.

Comment: I did find that BEA error description.  The weird thing is that I've been looking through this test code and have not found more than one consumer, for the same destination name anyway.  Of course, I'm assuming the exception doesn't lie, so there must be another one hidden in the code somewhere.